# Checking if character is a part of Latin alphabet?

Tags: java

I need to test whether character is a letter or a space before moving on further with processing. So, i

```
    for (Character c : take.toCharArray()) {
        if (!(Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isSpaceChar(c)))
            continue;

        data.append(c);
```

Once i examined the data, i saw that it contains characters which look like a unicode representation of characters from outside of Latin alphabet. How can i modify the above code to tighten my conditions to only accept letter characters which fall in range of [a-z][A-Z]?

Is Regex a way to go, or there is a better (faster) way?

Comment: Wait, why do you consider "é" to not be a letter? Usually people are looking for ways to make their code handle international input *better*, not *worse*...

Comment: @Borealid, In my case the control character is an oddity, which i am currently further investigating. `é` certainly is a valid character, which for the purposes of my program should not be there.

Comment: The regex to do this is to check against the Latin script property with `\p{sc=Latin}`.

Comment: Related: [*Identify if a Unicode code point represents a character from a certain script such as the Latin script?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62109781/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to strip out non-ASCII letter characters, then a quick approach is to use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and Regex:

```
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "")
```

Can't say anything about performance vs. a character by character scan and append to `StringBuilder`, though.

Comment: It appears in my testing that going 1 character at a time is about 30% faster. But certainly a valid suggestion and approach. Thank you

Comment: I'd be curious to see the results of with `s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+", "")` and `s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]*", "")`.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard Wow. Twice as fast as `[^a-zA-Z]+` Faster then the one by characters

Answer (score 18):

If you specifically want to handle only those 52 characters, then just handle them:

```
public static boolean isLatinLetter(char c) {
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the regular expression you specified for this.  It's easy to read and should be quite speedy (especially if you allocate it statically).

Comment: Could you provide an example to do it the right way? I'd like to see what's faster.

Comment: It's getting rather late in the day in this locality, so I'm afraid you'll have to wait for code, particularly if you want it to compile :)

Comment: But, as an aside, you might be overly concerned with speed at this time.  Surely this isn't the slowest operation you're performing?  It might be more efficient to optimize the time that a future developer (who might be you!) spends trying to understand this bit of code.