# Identify if a Unicode code point represents a character from a certain script such as the Latin script?

Tags: java, unicode, character, codepoint

[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) categorizes characters as belonging to a [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)), such as the [Latin script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)).

How do I test whether a particular character ([code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)) is in a particular script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java represents the various Unicode scripts in the [`Character.UnicodeScript`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html#LATIN) enum, including for example [`Character.UnicodeScript.LATIN`](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/). These match the [*Unicode Script Properties*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

You can test a character by submitting its [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer number to the [`of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html#of(int)) method on that enum.

```
int codePoint = "a".codePointAt( 0 ) ; 
Character.UnicodeScript script = Character.UnicodeScript.of( codePoint ) ;
if( Character.UnicodeScript.LATIN.equals( script ) ) { … }
```

Alternatively:

```
boolean isLatinScript = 
        Character.UnicodeScript.LATIN
        .equals( 
            Character.UnicodeScript.of( codePoint ) 
        )
;
```

Example usage.

```
System.out.println(
        Character.UnicodeScript.LATIN      // Constant defined on the enum.
        .equals(                           // `java.lang.Enum.equals()` comparing two constants defined on the enum.
            Character.UnicodeScript.of(    // Determine which Unicode script for this character.
                "".codePointAt( 0 )      // Get the code point integer number of the first (and only) character in this string.
            )                              // Returns a `Character.UnicodeScript` enum object. 
        )                                  // Returns `boolean`. 
);
```

See this [code run at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mHRiTu).

> false

FYI, the `Character` class lets you ask if a code point represents a character that [`isDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(int)), [`isLetter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(int)), [`isLetterOrDigit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(int)), [`isLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(int)), and more.